# Rubymine Close File Shortcut (Mac or Windows)

Tags: rubymine

How do I close the current file I'm working in (in Rubymine)? I don't want to click the 'x' because I hate the mouse, and I don't want to "close all modified" I simply want to close the current file that has focus, much like I can in any other program on Mac by pressing Command W.

Comment: If it still doesn't work for you, update the question with more details.

Answer (score 2):

I bet you've missed [this documentation section](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/closing-files-in-the-editor.html).

Shortcut would depend on the keymap and can be customized, but the default one is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> on Windows and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> on Mac.

Verify the shortcut in `Settings` | `Keymap`, make sure it doesn't conflict with other applications, try to map the `Close` action to a different shortcut. It works fine, I've double checked it.

Comment: On Mac OS 10.8 it's Fn-Cmd-F4 for Rubymine 5.4

Answer (score 1):

Command-W should work to close the current file in the current version of Rubymine (6.2)

Answer (score 0):

Ditto what CrazyCoder said.  Here are the exact steps to map Close and Close All windows to shortcut keys in Rubymine:

```
Rubymine | Preferences | Keymap | Main Menu | Edit | Select Word at Caret  >> Remove Keyboard Shortcut: command+W
Rubymine | Preferences | Keymap | Main Menu | Edit | Unselect Word at Caret  >> Remove Keyboard Shortcut: command+shift+W
Rubymine | Preferences | Keymap | Window | Editor Tabs | Close  >> Remove Keyboard Shortcut: command+F4
Rubymine | Preferences | Keymap | Window | Editor Tabs | Close  >> Add Keyboard Shortcut: command+W
Rubymine | Preferences | Keymap | Window | Editor Tabs | Close All >> Add Keyboard Shortcut: command+shift+W
```

Details here: http://lexsheehan.blogspot.com/2013/01/fixing-close-window-keyboard-shortcuts.html